# Simple present with past tense?

Tags: tense

I was looking for a book that was to be released by that time and opened the respective page saying " (name of the book) is released!".

How can that be possible? Shouldn´t it be the present perfect here because it is relevant for the present meaning that I can buy now? I don´t understand.

Comment: I would use "has been released" because the release of a book involves a number of processes over some period of time. As opposed to "He was released from prison." which would be a single event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passive sentences in English can be stative passives (describing a state) or dynamic (describing an action). Similarly, a form of "to be" plus the past participle can also be an adjective phrase rather than a passive expression.

> (Book) is released

This can be understood as the book is now in the state of being released (i.e. before it would be said "(Book) is unreleased").

> (Book) has been released

This would also be valid, but this would more emphasize the action/event.

Answer (score 0):

The book is about to be released, very soon. Remember, they probably want you to buy it. Sometimes there is a waiting list for books that haven`t been released yet. Once the book has been released, you can say it has been released, so now I can buy it.